# Column Value Range Filter in Hbase 0.94

Tags: filter, hbase

I want to use a range filter in hbase on more than one column . I know we can use SingleColumnValueFilter implementing And/Or Conditions but I want to run the same filter condition against two different columns.

Example:myhbase table

```
rowkey,cf:bidprice,cf:askprice,cf:product
```

I want to filter all the rows with `(cf:bidprice>10 and cf:bidprice<20) or (cf:askprice>10 and cf:askprice<20)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I figured it out. Below code snippet is an example implementation.

```
byte[] startRow=Bytes.toBytes("startrow");
byte[] endRow=Bytes.toBytes("stoprow");

SingleColumnValueFilter bidPriceGreaterFilter=new SingleColumnValueFilter("q".getBytes(), "bidprice".getBytes(), CompareFilter.CompareOp.GREATER_OR_EQUAL, "12345".getBytes());
SingleColumnValueFilter bidPricelesserFilter=new SingleColumnValueFilter("q".getBytes(), "bidprice".getBytes(), CompareFilter.CompareOp.LESS_OR_EQUAL, "12346".getBytes());
SingleColumnValueFilter askPriceGreaterFilter=new SingleColumnValueFilter("q".getBytes(), "askprice".getBytes(), CompareFilter.CompareOp.GREATER_OR_EQUAL, "12345".getBytes());
SingleColumnValueFilter askPricelesserFilter=new SingleColumnValueFilter("q".getBytes(), "askprice".getBytes(), CompareFilter.CompareOp.LESS_OR_EQUAL, "12346".getBytes());

FilterList andFilter1= new FilterList(FilterList.Operator.MUST_PASS_ALL);
andFilter1.addFilter(bidPriceGreaterFilter);
andFilter1.addFilter(bidPricelesserFilter);

FilterList andFilter2= new FilterList(FilterList.Operator.MUST_PASS_ALL);
andFilter2.addFilter(askPriceGreaterFilter);
andFilter2.addFilter(askPricelesserFilter);

FilterList finalFilterList=new FilterList(FilterList.Operator.MUST_PASS_ONE);
finalFilterList.addFilter(andFilter1);
finalFilterList.addFilter(andFilter2);

Scan scan = new Scan(startRow,endRow);
scan.setFilter(finalFilterList);
```