# Hbase Date Range

Tags: hbase

I am new to hbase.I have a column named date in Hbase.I need to create a query which will return me data between the Range of date.
E.g- 20140501,20140502,20140506.
These are the dates and query should give the result between the dates like 20140501 to 20140506.
That query should run in hbase shell.
I have tried following query which will give the result of that particular date. but I need range to be checked between two dates.
Query:

```
scan 'samlpe_test', {COLUMNS => ['Info'],FILTER => "(SingleColumnValueFilter('Info','date',=,'binary:20140102',true,false)) AND (SingleColumnValueFilter('Info','gender',=,'binary:female',true,false))"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using, SingleColumnValue filter with "=". You can also include <,>,<=,>= with that filter. So you can use **filter(>,20140501) AND filter(<=,20140505)**.

Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27574880/column-value-range-filter-in-hbase-0-94).

Please understand, that the more filters, the more is the latency. Because a scan occurs for the entire data and verifies the match